# Rails enqueue jobs and execute after x time from previous

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a rails api app where receives a bunch of requests and then, for each, it executes a job, but I want to prevent it job being called immediately, I need it delay 2 seconds. So for that I have `MyAwesomeJob.perform_in(2.seconds, stuff)`. So looking to sidekiq it goes right after 2 seconds. But next request goes right away.

What I need is: having 10 requests in 1 second it should enqueue 10 jobs and execute it one after other. (first gonna be in 2 seconds, next should wait last finish and go, so 4 seconds, 6seconds etc....)

Thanks!